# how to use the compare API of Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, compare

I want to catch the list of the changed methods between two versions of a program. I saw that Eclipse have a tool to compare files each others which match with my expectations. The corresponding API is org.eclipse.compare. I tried to use it but I failed.

Did anyone already use this API and could give me an example of a java program using this API.

The idea is that I have the string path of the two versions of the program in entry and I want to return the list of differences.

Thank you very much.

Thomas.

Comment: Did you get any error message? or Its doesnot show any difference between two API?

Comment: No, I just wanted to say that I don't understand how the API works and I have not any idea on what methods to call to compare the two projects. I think that it can help others users too to have an example for using this API. I keep on searching.

Comment: Did you take a look at http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/compare/package-summary.html#package_description?

Answer (score -1):

Why you are not using the linux diff command:
http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_diff.htm

Comment: Because this will be the first step of a java program I want to develop to select a subset of test cases impacted by the changes between two versions of a program.